# Clear Primefaces terminal

Tags: ajax, primefaces, terminal

I have designed a custom terminal using the Primefaces p:terminal tag.  Does anyone know of a way to clear the content of the terminal with the click of a button like they do on the Primefaces website?

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/terminal.jsf

I see that they use "onclick="PF('term').clear()"" but when I try it, I get an error that says that PF has not been defined.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need Elite 3.5.x to use clear feature, you are probably on old 3.5. version.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I actually am using PrimeFaces 4.0-SNAPSHOT.  It works in the showcase, but not in my code.

Comment: do you have xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" declared ?